# jquery select after get() insertion

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, live

I'm inserting rows into a table via a get() call to a php page, which works. I then want to update the row numbers of the table.

Jquery updates all the rows except the most recently inserted one.

```
$("#insert_row").click(function () {
    $.get("print_row.php", function(data){
        $("#table").append(data);
    });
});

$("#insert_row").on("click", function () {
    var rowNumber = 1;
        $(".rowNumColumn").each(function () {
            $(this).text(rowNumber);
            rowNumber++;
        })    
});
```

I've browsed the site for a while looking for an answer to this, and the solution appears to be the live() or on() modifiers. However I can't get that to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the renumbering in the callback of the `get`.  As it is now, you are renumbering prior to the `get` request returning.  `get` is simply a shortcut for making an `ajax` get request.  AJAX is asynchronous so it does not wait for the request to return before moving on.

```
$("#insert_row").click(function () {
    $.get("print_row.php", function(data){
        $("#table").append(data);

        var rowNumber = 1;
        $(".rowNumColumn").each(function () {
            $(this).text(rowNumber);
            rowNumber++;
        }) 
    });
});
```